# Add a Mongodb 3.6 member to a replica set running Mongodb 3.2

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to add a new Mongodb member to a replica set with all of the other servers running version 3.2 and I keep getting the error

> status: "IncompatibleServerVersion: Sync source had no feature compatibility version document"

I see that you can set the compatibility version of a mongo server to 3.2 or 3.4 but how do I set it on the 3.6 server so that it will perform an initial sync.

Comment: You don't want to do that. The error doesn't let you shoot own foot.  It may be okay to have different minor versions, but the gap between 3.2 and 3.6 so huge, that you cannot even upgrade 3.2 to 3.6 directly.

Comment: It seems that each version can be upgraded by one level but that is about it.   Atleast that is what I am seeing currently