# "Sync source had no feature compatibility version" error when adding MongoDB 3.6 member to 3.4 replica set

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to migrate a cluster from MongoDB 3.4 to 3.6.

When adding a new member which uses MongoDB 3.6, the initial synchronization fails with the following error:

> Sync source had no feature compatibility version document at src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp 679

As I can see, this is a [well-known error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49525788/240613) for those who try to migrate from 3.2 to 3.6. In my case, however, I'm trying to migrate from 3.4 (3.4.14 to be more specific, as reported by `db.version()` on every instance of the cluster) to 3.6. Since MongoDB official documentation makes no reference to the version 3.5, I'm not sure what am I supposed to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can definitely upgrade a replica set or sharded cluster from MongoDB 3.4 to 3.6. See the [upgrade guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/) relevant to your deployment. The error message you are receiving suggests you've missed a [prerequisite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#prerequisites) in prior upgrades: the replica set does not have **featureCompatibilityVersion** set to 3.4. This would be the case if you upgraded from a version of MongoDB older than 3.4 and hadn't enabled backwards-incompatible features yet.

Comment: MongoDB 3.5 (and releases with the second component being an odd number) are not referred to in the upgrade notes as those are development releases. See: [MongoDB version numbers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/#release-version-numbers). MongoDB 3.5 is the development release series leading up to the MongoDB 3.6 production release series.

Comment: @Stennie: that's it. The `featureCompatibilityVersion` was not set, specifically because the cluster was migrated from 3.2. Can you please promote your comments to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely [upgrade a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/) or [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-sharded-cluster/) from MongoDB 3.4 to 3.6. Upgrades are currently only supported between adjacent major releases, so before upgrading to MongoDB 3.6 you need to complete the upgrade to MongoDB 3.4.

> Sync source had no feature compatibility version document

This error message indicates that you've missed a prerequisite in prior upgrades: the replica set does not have `featureCompatibilityVersion` set to 3.4. This would be the case if you previously upgraded from a version of MongoDB older than 3.4 and haven't enabled backwards-incompatible features yet.

The Feature Compatibility Version (FCV) setting was added in MongoDB 3.4 to provide control over enabling [backwards-incompatible data features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#backwards-incompatible-features) that could complicate the downgrade process. For example, MongoDB 3.4 adds views, additional index formats (supporting collation and case-sensitive indexes), and a new Decimal BSON type.

After upgrading to 3.4 and confirming the likelihood of a downgrade is minimal, the FCV should be set using:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

This is a [prerequisite to upgrading to MongoDB 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#prerequisites) which has a similar final upgrade step to [enable backwards-incompatible 3.6 features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#enable-backwards-incompatible-newversion-features) by setting the FCV to "3.6".

You can check the current FCV using:

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
```

> Since MongoDB official documentation makes no reference to the version 3.5, I'm not sure what am I supposed to do.

MongoDB 3.5 (and releases with the second component being an odd number) are not referred to in the upgrade notes as those are development releases (see: [MongoDB version numbers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/#release-version-numbers)). MongoDB 3.5 is the development release series leading up to the MongoDB 3.6 production release series.